# what is the torque required by stepper motor to hold an object of 400 grams

Tags: stepper-motor

What is the torque required by a stepper motor to hold and fully rotate an object of about 400 grams ? I will be using an arduino uno along with the motor. The object will be mounted on a circular platform below which the motor and arduino will be placed.

Comment: This question is under-constrained - it is the rotational inertia that you need to know not the mass - inertia is related to mass but, if that mass is a shape of 1cm diameter and quite high it will present very little inertia.

Comment: Torque is studied in mechanics, not electronics. Adding the word "arduino" to the question doesn't automatically make it on-topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Torque is force times the lever length.

Let's say you have a wire attached to the object, and the wire is wound around a pulley which is mounted on the motor. In that case the torque you need to hold it steady is 4N*r where r is the radius of the pulley in meters.

A big pulley means you need a lot of torque, a small pulley requires less torque, but the motor will have to spin faster to get the same linear speed.